# Nagios check for a file on a website

Tags: linux, monitoring, website, nagios

I want to create a nagios check that test if a certain file is available on a public website and if that file contains a certain line of text.

From the command line I have been executing:

```
./check_http -H 192.168.1.2 -u http://192.168.1.2/index.html -t 5 -s "Company Name"
```

Which passes OK and fails if I delete the file or change the text it is looking for.

Now I want to incorporate this into my nagios config files.

I create a Host which has the address of the ip address above and create a service as follows.

```
check_command check_http!-u /index.html -t 5 -s "Company Name"
```

But if I change the filename it is checking or the text it is checking it still passes even though I know they don't exist on the website.

What am I doing wrong I think I must be testing a different file or something for it to always pass.

Comment: Can you have a look at the web server logs and see exactly what the request is, if it's a 200, or 404, or 500 etc, to begin with?

Comment: Can you show us the command_line value in the command definition as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are executing the command manually, you are calling **/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http** correct?

When you are calling **check_http** from the nagios config, it looks at **/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg** to determine the **check_http** command arguments.

What you need to do is create a custom check like:

```
define command {
    command_name                   check_web_content
    command_line                   $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 60 -w 15 -c 45 -u $ARG1$ -s $ARG2$
```

}

Then in your service configuration your check_command should be something like:

```
check_command check_web_content!http://www.domain.com/index.html!"Text on site"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. One question -w and -c are they what determine if the alerts is a warning or critical?

Comment: Yes, those are timeouts in seconds.  (I just grabbed the line I use in my nagios file - which uses custom timeouts)

Answer (score 6):

First you need to define a command:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_http
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ \
                    -u $ARG1$ -t $ARG2$ -s $ARG3$
}
```

Then for your host entry define the check_command as follows:

```
check_command    check_http!/index.html!5!"Company Name"
```

Comment: You might want to define a separate command like "check_http_text" to differentiate it from the default "check_http"

Answer (score 3):

You can set the following in the Nagios config too see what command is actually be executed ( see the expansion of the full command):

```
debug_level=-1
debug_verbosity=2
debug_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.debug
```

Comment: Are these options available on nagios 2.11 or were they only introduced in nagios 3?